# F# Save Data with EF in High Order Function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, f#, azure-sql-database

I am creating and inserting items into a database within an F# high order function.  I keep getting thrown an exception that says I am attempting to save 0 items to my database, but I am clearly adding items to the context and then saving.  Inspecting the db.WordRelations.Local property shows 728 items (none of which exist remotely).

```
let CreateWordRelationDB () =
    let db = new AnnotatorModel()
    printfn "%s" "Entered Function and created db v8"
    let tweets = db.Tweets.ToList() |> Seq.map(fun t -> t.Text)
    let words = db.Words.ToList() |> Seq.map(fun w -> w)
    words 
    |> Seq.fold(fun acc w1 ->  
                        let filtacc = acc 
                                      |> Seq.filter(fun (w2:Word) -> 
                                                        if(w1.Text = w2.Text) then false else true)
                        let adds = filtacc 
                                    |> Seq.map(fun w2 -> CreateWordRelation w1 w2 tweets)
                        db.WordRelations.AddRange(adds) |> ignore
                        try 
                            db.SaveChanges() |> ignore
                        with error -> 
                                printfn "%s" error.Message
                        filtacc
                    ) words
    |> ignore
```

db.SaveChanges() continually fails on me.  You can see just above it db.WordRelations.AddRange(adds).  Each iteration this quantity reduces, but starts at 728, then 727, then 726 etc etc till 0.

Any thoughts?

Comment: my initial thought is to separate your command from the query.  Write a query that returns a collection of exactly what you want to insert and then Seq.iter (fun x -> db.WordRelations.AddRange(x); db.SaveChanges() )

Comment: Giving that a shot and deploying.  That said...the only issue I run into is that this is a long running process and is currently on a small sample data set.  It can also die in the middle.  I also have a branch where a new dbcontext is created on each iteration to help speed things up a bit more by not maintaining changes throughout the whole process.

Comment: Got this result after modifying as you indicated - the crazy thing is, I don't see how this is happening.  The only thing touching this db is this process.  [08/27/2015 19:52:09 > a17117: INFO] Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that for some reason or another in my particular instance, SQL Azure or Entity Framework v6.1 did not like my primary key being a computed column, which was computed by taking the ID's of word one and word two and concatenating them together.

Changing ID to be called "PairId" and having Id be an Int IDENTITY column appears to have fixed all issues...

If anybody wants to comment on underlying reasons, I would be very fascinated to know those answers.